# Issue with redirection in HttpFilter

Tags: java, servlets, filter

I have a login.html page like below

```
<h2>Hello, please log in:</h2>
<br><br>
<form action="j_security_check" method=post>
    <p><strong>Please Enter Your User Name: </strong>
    <input type="text" name="j_username" size="25">
    <p><p><strong>Please Enter Your Password: </strong>
    <input type="password" size="15" name="j_password">
    <p><p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

Also I have an error page like below.

```
<h2>Login Incorrect, please log in:</h2>
<br><br>
<form action="j_security_check" method=post>
    <p><strong>Please Enter Your User Name: </strong>
    <input type="text" name="j_username" size="25">
    <p><p><strong>Please Enter Your Password: </strong>
    <input type="password" size="15" name="j_password">
    <p><p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
</html>
```

Both are configured in web.xml and is working fine. Now i have a filter where I do some validations(for minimizing the code am validating only user name == admin here) and if the validation fails am redirecting to the error.html like below.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)req;
        if(request.getUserPrincipal() != null){
            boolean result = validateUser(request.getUserPrincipal().getName());
            if(!result){
                HttpSession session  = request.getSession(false);
                session.invalidate();
                request.logout();
                request.getRequestDispatcher("/error.html").forward(req, resp);
                return;
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(req, resp);

    }
```

The code for validateUser is like below

```
public boolean validateUser(String name){
        boolean result = false;
        if("admin".equalsIgnoreCase(name)){
            result = true;
        }
        return  result;
    }
```

The filter mapping in web.xml is like

```
    <web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
  <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.listener.MyListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <filter>
        <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.Filter.LoginFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
      <!-- Roles -->
  <security-role>
    <description>Any rol </description>
    <role-name>*</role-name>
  </security-role>

      <!-- Resource / Role Mapping -->
  <security-constraint>
    <display-name>Area secured</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>protected_resources</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      <http-method>GET</http-method>
      <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <description>User with any role</description>
      <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>

  <login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>Tomcat SALES Application</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login.html</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/error.html</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
  </login-config>
</web-app>
```

So now when a user enters user id and password which are valid and user name not admin the user is navigated to error.html.But after this when a user enters the correct credentials its showing empty page with the below URL

**http://localhost:8080/webapps2/j_security_check**

Why is this issue happening ?

Comment: Have you analyzed console log? Are any exceptions thrown?

Comment: Can you please post the code for `validateUser` method? Hope that you are validating username using _equals_ method as `if(username.equals("admin")){//valid} else {//invalid - redirect to error page}`

Comment: could you please post the filter definition in your deployment descriptor? or are you using annotations?

Comment: @HardikModha There are no exceptions in the console.log. The validateUser code is updated in the question, but I dont think that is having any significance here.

Comment: @jsfviky The question is updated with the contents of the deployment descriptor contents,

Comment: @robin please post all of your deployment descriptor too, yesterday I've tried it and its working. Just want to make sure about your security roles, constraints and relative mappings.

Comment: @jsfviky how are you redirecting to the error page ?

Answer (score 0):

This is why the issue is happening: The protocol for login is:

1. Client sends in a request for a protected resource.
2. Container sends the configured form-login-page to the client.
3. Clients completes the login form and hits submit.
4. login form sends a j_security_check request to the server.
5. Container process the j_security check request and authenticates the
   user.

   5a. If user credentials are good the container redirects the request to the protected resource from step 1.

   5b. If user credentials are bad the container redirects to the configured form-error-page.

In your app, if the user is not "admin" you basically take over steps 4, and 5, and proceed with 5b. You then send in another j_security check which is now not part of a login.

I think, for your scenario, you should change the login-form-page to only allow submit if the user is "admin".

Comment: In my case I am performing step 4 and 5 and only if the login is valid the control will come to filter where am checking the user name is admin or not. The admin check is just for the sample , but in the real scenario i have to perform many checks.So I wont be able to do that in the login-form page